# Netbeans 7.3 how to set MAVEN_OPTS, e.g. MaxPermSize

Tags: maven, netbeans-7

When using Netbeans 7.3 how can I set the maven build action properties to set the MAVEN_OPTS.  E.g.

`-Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try right clicking on the project and setting an action with a property for `Env.MAVEN_OPTS` similar to this:

[image: screenshot]