# I use load time weaving in spring. How can i set class loader in jetty?

Tags: java, spring, jetty, classloader, load-time-weaving

I use load time weaving in spring. All works fine with websphere, because it has own class loader, but i have troubles in dev mode, where i use embedded jetty. How can i set class loader in jetty?

When i run it i see following error

```
[INFO] org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.weaving.AspectJWeavingEnabler#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loadTimeWeaver': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.instrument.classloading.ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLoader [com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload$WebAppClassLoaderExtension] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method.
```

Comment: Follow the instructions [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-aj-ltw-environment-generic) for Jetty LTW support (generic Java apps) in Spring.

Comment: Thanks for link. I read it, sorry i forget to mention about it. I run my app with -javaagent:path/to/spring-instrument.jar but it doesn't work anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've resolved it by adding a "-Xbootclasspath/a:[path to jar]" as JvmArgs param.
 Now it's looks like

```
<extraJvmArgs>-Xmx4g -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -javaagent:C:\Users\auldanov\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-instrument\3.1.4.RELEASE\spring-instrument-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\Users\auldanov\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-instrument\3.1.4.RELEASE\spring-instrument-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar</extraJvmArgs>
```